# Converting column names to upper case in a list of data frames using lapply explanation

Tags: r, function

This is probably a very simple problem but I have been struggling to search for this issue. Basically, I am using `lapply` to convert the column names to upper in a list of dataframes. My first attempt did not work, however adding `;x` works. What exactly is going on?

This does not work:

```
 df.list <- lapply(df.list,function(x) colnames(x) <- toupper(colnames(x)))
```

This does:

```
df.list <- lapply(df.list,function(x) {colnames(x) <- toupper(colnames(x));x})
```

Comment: You can do `lapply(df.list, function (x) dplyr::rename_with(x, toupper))`

Comment: @Phil There are alternatives to this solution and dplyr is a good but i'm wondering what ;x does generally in functions

Comment: Deleted my response, i misunderstood the question. The reason is because you were not returning anything in your first line of code within the function.

Comment: @Phil Ah I see - now I feel silly, thanks!

Comment: No such thing as feeling silly, I've asked much dumber questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are modifying the object x (or in this case only the colnames of x) inside the function definition, you have to return the modified object x. This is happening by using `;x` which can be read as a new line only returning the object `x`